# How do I set up relationship for large core data sets efficiently?

Tags: ios, json, core-data

I have two entities Drink and Breweries. I have the data in Json and I am building out core data tables for each and have a relationship set up (one to one for drink to brewery). However, trying to set this at the time of building out the Drink objects obviously slows down the process greatly because I am having to query core data every time I create a new drink (there are a couple thousand drinks and about 1000 breweries). At the moment the brewery has a unique id that matches to an attribute on the drink. What is the best way to go about this without slowing down load time greatly? I am considering just using one entity instead and placing the breweries in the same table even though that is bad DB practice.

Here is the code for building out the drink table from the json with the code for adding in the brewery commented out.

```
[jsonCategories enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    Drink *drink = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Drink" inManagedObjectContext:importContext];
    //drinkType.id = [obj objectForKey:@"id"];
    drink.name = [obj objectForKey:@"name"];
    drink.alcoholByVolume = [obj objectForKey:@"abv"];
    drink.drinkType = beerDrinkType;
    drink.breweryId = [obj objectForKey:@"brewery_id"];


//        NSArray *fetchedObjects;
//        NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
//        NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Breweries" inManagedObjectContext:importContext];
//        [fetch setEntity:entityDescription];
//        [fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id =%@", drink.breweryId]];
//        NSError *errorBrewery;
//        [fetch setFetchLimit:1];
//        fetchedObjects = [importContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&errorBrewery];
//        if (fetchedObjects && [fetchedObjects count] > 0){
//        Breweries *fetchedBrewery = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
//        drink.breweries = fetchedBrewery;
//        }

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-fetching the brewery list with each iteration of jsonCategories elements. This adds huge overhead and causes the slowness, and is unnecessary because I assume the list does not change.

A better design is to fetch it once, and then filter it as needed. I’ve omitted some code below and only wrote the important parts, you should be able to fill it in yourself.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = …;
// Note that predicate is not set here
fetchedBreweries = [importContext executeFetchRequest…];
[jsonCategories enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    …
    NSArray *matchingBreweries = [fetchedBreweries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:…predicate];
    drink.breweries = matchingBreweries.firstObject;
}];
```

Maybe this will also be slow, because if you fetch all the breweries, it might consume too much CPU and memory (though I’d first try it to see if this is really a problem).

A further optimization could be that you first iterate over jsonCategories and create a set of brewery ID-s that are found in the results. Then, you fetch only these breweries, and then iterate over the drink results again to add breweries to drinks. This would be something like

```
NSMutableSet *breweryIds = [NSMutableSet set];
[jsonCategories enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    …
    [breweryIds addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"brewery_id"]];
}];
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id in %@", breweryIds]];
NSArray *breweries = [importContext executeFetchRequest…]
for (Drink *drink in drinks) {
    NSArray *matchingBreweries = [fetchedBreweries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:…predicate];
    drink.breweries = matchingBreweries.firstObject;
}
```

Hm. I need a beer now.

Comment: Actually on testing it on my phone (5), it takes a full 40 seconds to build both the drink database and brewery database and then filter the fetched brewery array with a predicate. I can't really think of a way to make this faster so I might just have to replace the id's with the actual brewery names.